# How to use a custom docker image with Azure Databricks

Tags: docker, azure-databricks

How to use a custom docker image with Azure databricks?

I am using an azure databricks notebook for ML, but I would like to bring a custom docker.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT Can you post your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this for some time, and on a high level, you need to perform the following steps:

1. Build and upload your custom Docker image to Azure container registry.
2. Create and start a cluster from the container in Azure container registry.
3. Run your notebook with model training on the cluster created.

IMPORTANT: Clusters that support custom images (Standard runtime) don't have the ML features like automatic experiment tracking, etc. built into ML runtimes. So, you either need to customize an ML runtime cluster with installing the necessary libraries and using all the benefits of Databricks ML features, or build a custom image, run a Standard runtime cluster from it and you will have to control all the ML features manually.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/runtime/mlruntime